How can I run a local application using JavaFx on intellij?
/Users/ashwin/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java --module-path ~/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib. --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Djava.library.path=~/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib. -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49194:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/ashwin/Desktop/RPGenerator/Random Password Generator/out/production/Random Password Generator:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.web.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.base.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.media.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/Users/ashwin/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.11/lib/javafx.graphics.jar PasswordApp
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Process finished with exit code 1

This is the error I get when trying to run a local app. I am using OpenJDK-22.
I have tried JavaFx version 22 and 17. I keep getting the error that javafx.controls not found, even though it is in the lib. directory.

The [java] command contains both --module-path and -classpath. It should only contain --module-path. The [JavaFX] JAR files are given in the -classpath but they should not be. They should be in the --module-path. I don't use IntelliJ so I can't tell you how to fix that.

It’s a different error messsge, but the intention and solution are the same (running a JavaFX project in Idea) as this potential duplicate.

The command looks wrong as you've mixed lib and lib., ~ and /Users/... and there is spaces in classpath but no quotes though that may simply be how you printed it rather than inputted it.

Method 1:
Add JavaFX Local Lib to Project
(1) New Project

Name: hellofx2
Language: Java
Build system: IntelliJ

Click Button Create

(2) Menu
File -> Project Structure...

(3) Project Settings -> Libraries -> +

(4) New Project Library
Select Java

(5) Select Library Files
Find your JavaFX SDK directory ,
Select lib
Click OK

(6) You can find add lib
Click OK

(7) Project Directory
Example java code from JavaFX project using IntelliJ’s template.
└── src
    ├── com
    │   └── example
    │       └── hellofx
    │           ├── HelloApplication.java
    │           ├── HelloController.java
    │           └── hello-view.fxml
    └── module-info.java

(8) module-info.java
module com.example.hellofx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.example.hellofx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.hellofx;
}

(9) HelloApplication.java
package com.example.hellofx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

(10) HelloController.java
package com.example.hellofx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}

(11) hello-view.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.hellofx.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>

(12) Run

(13) Commad Line:
cd out/production/hellofx2

/home/demo/.sdkman/candidates/java/22.0.1-tem/bin/java \
-Dvisualgc.id=7010813876756 \
-Djava.library.path=/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib \
-javaagent:/home/demo/TOOLS/idea-IC-232.10203.10/lib/idea_rt.jar=37209:/home/demo/TOOLS/idea-IC-232.10203.10/bin \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 \
-Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 \
-classpath /home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.web.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.media.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.swing.jar \
-p /home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/home/demo/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib/javafx.base.jar:/home/demo/Documents/Examples_JavaFX/hellofx2/out/production/hellofx2 \
-m com.example.hellofx/com.example.hellofx.HelloApplication


Method 2:
Use Maven Lib.
JavaFX project using IntelliJ’s template
Create your JavaFX project using IntelliJ’s template
Here is a walk-through using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.
(1) IDEA Menu
File -> New -> Project...

(2) New Project Window
JavaFX

Name: hellofx
Language: Java
Build system: Maven

Click Button Next

(3) Click Create or select more Additional libraries (or keep no selection)

(4) Open HelloApplication.java
Click Run Icon

(5) Show Hello Window

Verify module-info.java
Open the module-info.java file in your project. This file is part of the Java Platform Module System (JPMS).
Add this line: requires javafx.controls;
Check if IntelliJ IDEA shows any error or hints, then fix it.
module com.example.hellofx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens com.example.hellofx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.hellofx;
}

